# apt-get broken after ubuntu upgrade to 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, apt-get

I upgraded ubuntu from version 12.04 to 14.04 and now I get several system errors when I log in and in a terminal I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

...
```

Update: I can't run rm with sudo:

```
$ sudo rm filename.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You should ask this on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer:

I had to reboot in recovery mode as root and do:

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libpam-smbpass
```

Then

```
apt-get install -f
```

then I had to move some files to make it go through. There were some conflicts with samba packages that broke sudo...